# Meaning of "à" in the French salutation "à demain" etc.?

Tags: prépositions, salutations

Could you explain the meaning of *à* in French?

I know *à* in French can mean "in", "with", "to".
But I don't understand the meaning of "*à*" in the salutation, clearly.

For instance with *à demain*, *à bientôt*.

Comment: "jusqu'**à** ce qu'on se retrouve demain/bientôt/plus tard" ?

Comment: I'd say it's the meaning of "to", like in "I'm going to Paris", but with a moment in time instead of a place. You are envisaging somewhere in time. Quick Marty!

Comment: Here "à" means "**until/till**" -> "à demain" = "until tomorrow", "à la prochaine" = "until next time", "à la revoyure" = "until we meet again" (this also supports @Ahalone-zee's claim because originally, "jusqu'à" = "until").

Comment: Well. Could you comment in english? I have just started to study french.

Comment: Everything so far has been in English, except for the first comment, which I repeated in my comment.

Comment: It seems that there are only controversial possible explanations. So, maybe I have to think I can't match "à" in a salutation to a specific preposition. Right?

Answer (score 3):

"*à demain*" is meaning you will see the other person the next day, and the "*à*" would probably be translated "*to/until*".
And I think that "tomorrow" contains its "*à*" already (***to***morrow).

Just a fact:
In my local language (nothern Fr - Picardy) there is a shortenned expression to say "*à demain*" which is "*a dé*".

Comment: "à" does not mean "to" in this context. It means "to" in expressions like "I'm looking forward *to tomorrow*" -> "j'ai hâte d'être *à demain*." Also, tomorrow is just a word, it does not contain "to" as a preposition, it's just part of the word, like together or today or toenail.

Comment: Nicely spotted, "*the morrow*" is an obsolete English word that means "*the day after"*, "*the next day*" (French: "*le lendemain*"). So "*tomorrow*" probably comes from "*to morrow*".

Comment: @MorganFR Do you have some source that explains it's *until* and not *to*? Because to me it makes more sense if it's *to*.

Comment: @SimonDéchamps Unfortunately I cannot really find a source because "until" and "to" are both more widely used in other expressions rather than greetings ("I don't have to work until tomorrow" or "looking forward to tomorrow"). However there are some greetings like "until tomorrow" and "until we meet again" that use "until" (and they are translated using "à demain/la prochaine", and none I've ever heard of using "to". "To tomorrow" is not a greeting. It is however an expression in the likes of "To infinity and beyond!" The "morrow" part is indeed true but "to" does not make it a greeting.

Comment: https://www.duolingo.com/comment/473634 is a start, I guess

Comment: I'm not saying "*to tomorrow*" exists in English, but I feel like the "*à*" in "*à demain*" is more like "*to*" (a precise moment in the future you are pointing out) than "*until*" (a time interval between now and a moment in the future). What I mean is, if you say "*until tomorrow*", it feels like you say "*we won't see each other until tomorrow, let's do our own stuff untill we meet again tomorrow*", but when you say "*à demain*", it feels like you're pointing out a precise moment of time and say "*we will meet again tomorrow*". But it's only my own feeling.

Comment: tomorrow is a word, I was just talking about etymology (which helps in every language to understand the meanings).
I edited my answer about the fact part.

Comment: @SimonDéchamps "à demain" means exactly the same thing, mainly "on se revoit demain" and does not convey the idea of "to". "To tomorrow" on its own can mean either a destination (example time machine -> "to tomorrow!" instead of a shuttle saying "to Mars!"), and it can also be a toast ("to tomorrow!" as in "to the bride and groom!"), but certainly not "see you tomorrow". Therefore "until next time" means "à la prochaine", and is also a shortened version of "(je te dis aurevoir jusqu')à la prochaine (fois où on se verra)."

Comment: @MorganFR So we disagree on that point, I feel like "*à demain*" has the meaning of a destination in time and convey the idea of "to". It's a shame we can't find a source about the origin of the expression.

Comment: @SimonDéchamps At the bottom of [this link](http://dictionary.reverso.net/french-english/A%20demain!)(examples of "à demain" in context), there is also an example of "à demain" and "à la prochaine" translated using "until". You can click for more examples and there are expressions with "until" and "to" (you can filter them), so feel free to register and check out the hundreds of examples in there (most of the "until" and the "to" will have nothing to do with this case, but some will,using "until").also [this](http://context2.reverso.net/info.php?q=A+demain!&langFrom=fr&langTo=en&langTot=fr-en)

Comment: @MorganFR Since "Jusqu'à demain !" doesn't exist in French to say "'Till tomorrow!", and "To tomorrow!" doesn't exist in English to say "A demain !", one of the translations for *à demain* can be *'till tomorrow*, yes, but it doesn't mean it's a word-for-word translation and that *à demain* = *jusqu'à demain*. And as you can see, most of the examples translate *à demain* to *see you tomorrow*, which keep the idea of the destination in time.

Answer (score 2):

*À demain* est une « formule par laquelle on prend congé jusqu'au lendemain » ([Larousse](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/demain/23184/locution?q=demain#170759)). Comme c'est une [*formule*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/formule/34671?q=formule#34632), l'analyse est possiblement plus difficile et moins productive. Il y a une grande [richesse](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?Th=1&Th_id=97) dans l'emploi des prépositions. Dans un syntagme verbal, la préposition *à* sert généralement à construire un complément du verbe ([TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A0)). Elle « établit une relation syntaxique qui s'accompagne parfois d'un rapport de but, de moyen, de lieu, de temps, etc. » ([Larousse](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/%C3%A0/5?q=%C3%A0) ; voir aussi [BDL](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=4327)).

Essentiellement, on a ici une locution/[mot-phrase](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mot-phrase) composé d'une préposition (*à*) et d'un adverbe de temps ([*demain*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/demain)), employé en interjection. Sous l'angle de la préposition, on le range avec le complément circonstanciel de temps, sous le type qui « **marque une durée dont on vise le terme** » [+- "marking a period of time for which we seek the conclusion"], comme dans *à brève échéance*, la préposition se combinant plutôt ici à un adverbe de temps ([TLFi, I.E.3](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A0) : *à [bientôt](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/bient%C3%B4t), à demain, à [tantôt](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/tant%C3%B4t)* ; aussi avec la préposition *dans* dans le parler populaire : *à dans quinze jours*). En contexte verbal, ce parcours dont procède le moment visé serait la nuance d'avec l'emploi où l'on situe exactement le procès (du verbe) dans le temps (*il est arrivé à huit heures*) ; mais les nuances abondent et il reste que l'on prend congé en fixant un rendez-vous au lendemain avec cette formule invariable dont l'analyse est surtout théorique, si intéressante...

Comment: @Hyeongnam Jang If you need any help with this, let me know. Whether that yields _in a little while_, _until then_ or just a plain _see you tomorrow_ isn't very helpful because _à demain_ is somewhat of a set expression. The prep. _à_ can do a great many things, such as introducing a point in time, for a meeting, or it can stress the duration preceding that but figuring out whether _à demain_ does the latter is more or less insightful. I encourage to take a look at the TLFi entry for _à_ but it could be excruciatingly difficult so look at the "richesse" link for simpler examples.